# Intent.ACTION_VIEW - Multiple files

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a requirement to show multiple files (2 or more each of images, music or video, but only one type).  Given a series of thumbnails or filenames, the user should be able to select a chekbox and preview the selection.  IF the user selects multiple images, I want to be able to show ONLY those images selected. If he selects multiple mp3 files, I want to be able to play ONLY those songs.

If the user selects only one file, that's easy to do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  

if (someType == IMAGE) {
   i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile),"image/*");
}
else 
   if (sometype == VIDEO) {
      i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile),"video/mp4");
   }
   else if (someType == MUSIC) {
       i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(musicFile),"audio/mpeg");
   }  
startActivity(i);
```

However, if the user selects two or more of one type, how can I architect the intent to use whatever image/audio/video apps the user may have installed? Don't want to write custom players/viewers as I know an existing app can do this.

I am trying to mimic the functionality of a cloud app called "AllShare Play" (https://www.samsung.com/us/2012-allshare-play/) . This app does exactly what I need to do in my app - allows the user to "preview" multiple files and uses just the standard "Gallery" app for images, standard music app for songs, etc.  In each case, only the files selected are shown or played using standard apps each Android device is loaded with, so I know it's possible to do without writing a viewer or player.

Anyone have any ideas how to send multiple files via Intent.ACTION_VIEW to an external app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no android standard for send multible to ACTION_VIEW.

But there is a standard for [ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) where the files are transfered via EXTRA_STREAM.

for a working sendmultible example see [Secure-Photo-Viewer](https://github.com/Somethingweirdhere/Secure-Photo-Viewer): you select multible images from a gallery app and send them to Secure-Photo-Viewer.

If your app is the only sender and receiver of this intent you can use the same mechanism with ACTION_VIEW, too.

To learn more on intent communication you can use the [intent-intercept](https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept/) app that allows sending and receiving many types of intents

here is the code i use to send multible images

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (selectionCount == 1) {
            Long imageId = mSelectedItems.first();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, getUri(imageId));
        } else {
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            for (Long mSelectedItem : mSelectedItems) {
                uris.add(getUri(mSelectedItem));
            }
            sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Using SEND_MULTIPLE is an interesting approach, but it dodges the original question — how does one use a standard gallery app for viewing? It [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/0cc977e/AndroidManifest.xml?autodive=0) does not appear to have Intent filter for SEND_MULTIPLE. It does however have some interesting `action.VIEW` filters for `vnd.android.cursor.dir/*` types. I have a hunch, that those may be used with a custom ContentProvider for some interesting results.

Comment: For me it was not clear (a) if you are searching for a standard (there is none), (b) if you just want to address how samsumg-gallery does it or (c) how it could be done similar to a standard. I answered (c) while i assume you arelooking for (b). good look. I hope that intent intercept helps you find out how communication between samung-"AllShare Play" and samsung-Gallery works. if you found it out please let us know here so i can add this to [my own gallery app](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/), too

Comment: if you want to view all images in on dir Intent.ACTION_VIEW + intent.setDataAndType("file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myalbum/","image/*"); work for some galleries (i.e. simple-gallery)